# delete email address from invitation if user has signed up

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth

There is a situation that when a user has requested for invitation, he/she will then get to signup the account. When request is accepted by admin then they can signup which i have done. But i have no idea on how to delete the email address from the invitation table once that user has signed up successfully. I am using **django allauth** package.

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and settings.INVITE_MODE:
            try:
                obj = Invitation.objects.get(email=email)
                if not obj.request_approved:
                    self.add_error('email', 'Sorry your invitation is still in pending')
            except Invitation.DoesNotExist:
                invitation = Invitation.objects.create(email=email)
                self.add_error('email', 'Sorry at this time you are not invited. But we have added you to our invite list')
        elif email is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email field should not be empty')
        else:
            return email

class Invitation(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name=_("e-mail Address"))
    invite_code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=5)
    request_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('request accepted'))
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Invitation)
def send_email_when_invite_is_accepted_by_admin(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    request_approved = instance.request_approved
    if request_approved:
        subject = "Request Approved"
        message = "Hello {0}! Your request has been approved. You can now signup".format(instance.email)
        from_email = None
        to_email = [instance.email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True)
```

Comment: Lock the particular row by first picking the row using e = invitation.objects.get(email = ) and delete the entry by using e.delete()

Comment: where should i see that?

Comment: Invitation table, isn't it ?

Comment: yes but only if user has signed up not when accepted for signup because he/she might signup after some time.

Comment: If so, delete the entry in invitations once they complete sign-up. You need to find out when they have completed their sign-up and as a cascading effect, delete the entry in invitation table.

Comment: I could not check if the email address that is requested for invitation has completed sign up or not.